# How to use value() as sum_range for SUMIFS in Excel

Tags: excel

I tried to get total hours worked by each department with the following formula but it says there is a problem with the formula

```
=sumifs(VALUE(WeeklyPerformance[Hours Worked]),WeeklyPerformance[Department],UNIQUE(WeeklyPerformance[Department],,))
```

The data sheet is locked and type for Hours Worked is 2 which is text. I also tried simply remove value() in my formula but it will only return value as 0.

Comment: can you try with SUMPRODUCT instead of SUMIFS

Comment: Use `--` to suppress text to values which are stored as text.

Comment: @Will I tried SUMPRODUCT too but because raw data is text and result is 0 too

Comment: @Harun24hr sry I'm a bit confused about the -- part, eventually I want to get the result by using 1 formula

Comment: I tried to use below and it doesn't work too           
=SUMIFS(WeeklyPerformance[Billable Amount]/WeeklyPerformance[Hourly Rate ($)],WeeklyPerformance[Office],UNIQUE(WeeklyPerformance[Office],,))